# Sending raw multipart data through jquery $.post() and php

Tags: php, file-upload, jquery, curl, multipart

i need to send raw multipart data with a php POST but without an html form... im starting the process with jquery $.post() instead (the objective is to change a twitter account's background).

How can i achieve that? This is my current (and still incomplete) code:

1) Image filename is inserted in this hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="profile_background_image_url" value="oats.jpg" />
```

2) when clicking on the submit button, a javascript function is triggered... and it calls:

```
$.post('helper.php',{
 profile_background_image_url:$('#profile_background_image_url').val()
});
```

3) **helper.php** has

```
$param = array();
$param['image'] = '/www/uploads/'.$_POST['profile_use_background_image'];
$status = $connection->post('account/update_profile_background_image',$param);
```

**Notes**:

1. all the background files are inside the */www/uploads* local directory.
2. im using Abraham Williams' twitteroauth library 0.2

Bottom line, in step three i need to send **$param['image']** in *raw multipart data* to the **$connection** object (twitter library).

Any ideas?

Some references: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/account/update_profile_background_image

Comment: Would `file_get_contents()` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah i see now that hes building the post fields array into a query string which means you have to manually set the content type and that the `@` key in the `image` fields wont do its magic since that only works with an array argument. More importantly i dont see a way to modify the headers without hacking the library or extending it and replacing certain functions.

---

I would try would be prepending `@` to the file path of the `image` param like:

```
$param['image'] = '@/www/uploads/'.$_POST['profile_use_background_image'];
```

That is the convenient way to do it with cURL, and it looks like the libray basically uses cURL to make the request, so that should work.

Answer (score 0):

solved!

```
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        if(is_array($files)){
          $post_file_array = array();
          foreach($files as $key=>$value){
             $post_file_array[$key] = "@{$value}";
          }
          curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_file_array);
          if (!empty($postfields)) {
            $url = "{$url}?{$postfields}";
          }
        }
        else if (!empty($postfields)) {
          curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        }
```